# How to create a MySQL user without password - needed for remote login - to be used in bash insert script?

Tags: mysql, bash

My requirement is to create a user for remote login but without a password. At my remote space I use a bash script to do inserts, which is something like:

```
for i in {1..5000}; do
  mysql -h 11.40.3.169 -uUser -pPass -DDatabaseName <<<
    "insert into DatabaseTableName values('$i','dummy_$i');" &
  echo -n "$i  "
  sleep 1
  date
done
```

The problem is that each insert is taking almost 4 seconds, and I can not pinpoint the problem to anything but authentication at every insert. So, if I could create a user in MySQL with minimal authentication involved...Something like:

```
# I'm trying to remove this password
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

...Anything you can suggest.

Comment: I know this is a little late but: have you tried looping through the numbers to create all the queries first. Putting those queries in a file and then passing that file into mysql to batch execute?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do this by creating a user with a password and then placing a .my.cnf file in the home directory of the account which runs the bash script containing the following:

```
[mysql]
user=user
password=pass
[mysqladmin]
user=user
password=pass
```

This might be better than creating a user with no password.

Comment: Thanks a lot cbz for quick answer, I read a similar thing some where on net, but cold not make sens of it...where exactly do I need to keep this ?! (sorry if I sound dumb)..kindly help.

Comment: In the home directory belonging to the user that will run the bash script - in this case, probably your 'remote space'

Comment: You mean say, from the remote machine, in which I login as 'SomeUser', and then run the bash script, I should go to the home directory after I've logged in the remote machine as 'SomeUser' and keep the my.cnf file, which contains only the information as provided in your answer ?!

Comment: If I login to this remote linux server through a ssh client (PuTTy), using a username and password I have on the linux based server...where do I store it then ?! ..thanks a lot for still replying..

Comment: OK, probably the last question if it does work - I found the file at \etc\my.cnf on the linux server, I should add the stuff you said to it..right ?!(though I do not have permission to edit..but I can find someone who does), and after I have done so, how would my mysql access command etc. change ??

Comment: You are not replying, and I wanted to ask here..am I looking for my.cnf in \etc, or actually I need to add those lines to .my.cnf file (a new file), and keep it where ?!, sorry to bother you..but whom shud I ask !

Comment: You need to store it in the home directory on your remote account - if you don't understand what that means then i can't help.

Comment: It worked @cbz...and I'm sorry if my lack of linux knowledge bothered you...thanks !

Comment: No worries - but you might also want to read a basic unix book in the background, it might help understanding terminology.

Answer (score 42):

Just remove the `IDENTIFIED BY` part:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%'
```

Note that remote login from anywhere without a password is a very insecure thing. You better limit the allowed `IP` range for this user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES  ON *.* TO 'user'@'allowed_remote_machine'
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply Quassnoi, but the 2 commands you stated gave error and are not allowed, at least on MySQL 5.1 [ERROR 1133 (42000): can't find any matching row in the user table]..I had tried them before, and tried them again after reading your answer...please help me with this problem..and thanks for the insecure issue advice.

Comment: @Chirayu: you have `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` on. Issue `CREATE USER 'user'@'allowed_remote_machine'` first. Also, please pay attention to @cbz's advice: this is what you probably want instead of creating a user with no password.

Comment: well..your idea worked..thanks a lot..but my whole idea to reduce the remote insert's happening in the bash script to as fast possible still fails....as it still takes almost 4 seconds to do 1 insert...any wise words about that ?!, will cbz's answer help ?

Comment: @Chirayu: make two inserts in a row in the same session and see if that's a problem.

Comment: The thing is if I use the bash script as given in my question, even with no password (my stupid attempt), each INSERT still takes 4 secs..If I sue a command like - **time mysql -h 11.40.3.179 -ucd -DDatabaseName <<<'select * from DatabaseTableName;'** , it still takes 4.5 secs......it is only if I log into the mysql from remote location, and start doing the INSERTS, SELECTS etc, that it happens really-really fast..like milliseconds...

Comment: Would you a mechanism where mysql prompt is ready at remote logging space..but the INSERTS happen through that and not through a Bash script.. (I'm talking of a lottt of inserts) ...sorry to bother..but I'm just thankful people are replying to me.

Comment: Was insterested in password-less login from localhost. This method works good, but I discovered what mysql did not checks mysql_user == shell_user, so I can freely access database from any user, just by running mysql -u passwordless_user_name. So, seems, only postgresql have safe passwordless logins.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem lies in the fact that you are starting the mysql client for each insert. You should be doing your inserts from a php, java, etc program - not from a shell script.

The startup time of the client (and connection to the host) is killing you. I routinely do 1000s of inserts per minute from a php or java program to a MySQL database with millions of records on a small (CPU/memory) machine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so good idea to have a user without password and all privileges. I suggest you to create a user without password but just with some privileges (insert to specific table or specific database).

Comment: I'm ready to do what you suggested, but the road block is that I'm unable to create a user without a password in any scenario..read the comments in other answers to understand more...help if possible.

Comment: I think the best solution is proposed by cbz. Just add your user and password to your options file.

Comment: apologies for my lack of linux knowledge..but where exactly should I keep the my.cnf file as suggested by @cbz ??, I'm logging into the linux server, remotely by a ssh client (putty), using a username and password I have on that server...

Answer (score 0):

First off, using a client cnf file on the remote machine running the script wont speed this up. MySQL client is still sending logon information and logging in for each insert, it's just reading.a file for uid/pw instead of using cmd line arguments. AFAIK The network and authentication overhead are identical. Even the network packet contents will be the same.

You should still use a cnf file..

The way to.improve performance is to do multi-line linserts:

```
MySQL --defaults-file=/some/uid/pw/etc/.client.cnf -e \
"Insert into 
  tbl_name
    ('fld1','fld2')
  values
    ('r1-fld1','r1-fld2'),
    ('r2-fld2','r2-fld2'),
...and so on (up to max_allowed_packet_size)
    ('r500-fld2','r500-fld2');"
```

Or READ DATA INFILE on server side after shipping over the data file